# How does Frogg Toggs Polypropylene measure up?

Tags: hiking, rain-gear

I saw a new product for rain protection the other day. Frogg Toggs makes a line of rain gear out of a polypropylene material that I have not previously seen used for rain gear.

Does anyone know how this measures up to other hiking rain gear in terms of weight and rain resistance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polypropylene based rain gear is a subject of great debate. It seems to fit some people's needs perfectly while it is terrible for others. Frogg Toggs is one company, I know DriDucks is another. They both seem to get similar reviews, hot or cold.

The material leads to very lightweight rain gear compared to equally breathable/water resistant materials. So it should be as lightweight if not better than anything out there. Because of this it also offers little to no warmth, so if you are going into cold and rainy weather you will need an under layer.

Many of the complaints are about the durability. I have not had any problem with this but I may not be as hard of my gear as others are. My backpacking trips are mostly weekends on US East Coast. Climates with more rain the durability issue may be worse with packing and unpacking more often. I believe the durability comes from difficulty in assembling the material, which is also why it is never stylish. This issue may be improved as time goes on.

Rain resistance is very good, on par with the best competing materials.

Comment: A note on durability - I bought two sets of jackets and pants, and ripped the seat out of both of them before I even got to the trail :)  I think it was mostly a fit issue though, I found that I was swimming in the jacket, but the pants fit snugly.  YMMV!

Comment: Thank you.  I backpack primarily on the east coast, so it's good to hear from someone in a similar climate.

Comment: I had a set for few years, mostly it was used by my kids at their backpacking trips, I took it out few times.  It seemed prety sturdy, I was definitely not afraid of ripping it, but after it got really muddy and had to be washed few times, it started sheding fibers.  You could pull handfuls of fibers from it.  As far as I can tell, it still seems to work, though.

Comment: DriDucks are also FroggTogg brand, just the lighter weight and less durable version. I use DriDucks while backpacking in the Rockies.